# PageFilter in asp.net core razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, filter, razor-pages

I created a "PageFilter" razor page and I want to have this handler filter only run in my Admin Area method.
What do I need to do?

I use this, but this run handler filters all of my project handlers.

```
services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
             options.Filters.Add<SecurityPageFilter>();
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `PageFilter` just apply to the razor page in area, You can use `AddAreaPageApplicationModelConvention(xxx)` to achieve it.

For example, If you want your filter only apply to the `Index` razor page under `Admin` folder in area, you can register your filter like:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddAreaPageApplicationModelConvention(
                "Admin","/Index",
                    model => model.Filters.Add(new SampleAsyncPageFilter()));
            });
```

Please refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection.addareapageapplicationmodelconvention?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: tanks that work